# Why scheduled event is not deleting data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I'm using php and mysql. Inserting data into a datetime field using date(Y-m-d H:i:s) in codeigniter.

```
CREATE EVENT AutoDeleteRows
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 SECOND 
DO 
DELETE LOW_PRIORITY FROM a_database.event_temp_users 
WHERE registration_date< DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

After 1 minute i'm refreshing the table but the data is still there. The event is runnning every 30 seconds and it deletes all rows which are 1 minute or more old, isn't it?

Using phpmyadmin and InnoDB engine.

EDIT
Even if i do

```
CREATE EVENT AutoDeleteRows
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 SECOND 
DO 
DELETE LOW_PRIORITY FROM a_database.event_temp_users 
WHERE registration_date< DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

It is still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your event should be run every 30 seconds, you've got to use:

```
CREATE EVENT AutoDeleteRows
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 SECOND 
DO 
DELETE LOW_PRIORITY FROM a_database.event_temp_users 
WHERE registration_date< DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

instead.

> To repeat actions at a regular interval, use an EVERY clause.

With AT your event will only executed once at this certain point in time:

> AT timestamp is used for a one-time event. It specifies that the event executes one time only at the date and time given by timestamp, which must include both the date and time, or must be an expression that resolves to a datetime value.

both from the chapter [CREATE EVENT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html)

You will have to check, if the event scheduler is running. This can be done with

```
SELECT @@event_scheduler;
```

If the result should be `OFF` and you've got the right to start the event scheduler then you can activate the event scheduler with

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 'ON';
```

See [Event Scheduler Configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html)

> The global event_scheduler system variable determines whether the
> Event Scheduler is enabled and running on the server. It has one of
> these 3 values, which affect event scheduling as described here:
>
> - OFF: The Event Scheduler is stopped. The event scheduler thread does not run, is not shown in the output of SHOW PROCESSLIST, and no scheduled events are executed. OFF is the default value for event_scheduler.
>
> When the Event Scheduler is stopped (event_scheduler is OFF), it can be started by setting the value of event_scheduler to ON. (See next item.)
>
> - ON: The Event Scheduler is started; the event scheduler thread runs and executes all scheduled events.
> - DISABLED: This value renders the Event Scheduler nonoperational. When the Event Scheduler is DISABLED, the event scheduler thread does not run (and so does not appear in the output of SHOW PROCESSLIST). In addition, the Event Scheduler state cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: But CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 SECOND is the same as EVERY 30 SECOND, isn't it?

Comment: No, it isn't. It's just a one time execution 30 seconds after creating the event. Then never again.

Comment: ok, but it is not even running one time, if it would run atleast one time rows would have been deleted.

Comment: You can verify your event i.e. with a query against the information_schema: `SELECT * from information_schema.events WHERE event_name = 'AutoDeleteRows';`. Of main interest should be the `last_executed` column.

Comment: Can you execute the DELETE statement in a mysql client? And what's the result of the columns, `event_definition`, `event_type`, `interval_value`, `interval_field` and `status` of the query of last comment?

Comment: `DELETE LOW_PRIORITY FROM a_database.event_temp_users 
WHERE registration_date< DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)` working fine and deleting the data

Comment: event_definitation:`DELETE LOW_PRIORITY FROM a_database.event_temp_users 
WHERE registration_date< DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)`

Comment: event_type: RECURRING , interval_value: 30, interval_field:SECOND, status: enabled

Comment: Is the event scheduler running? You can check that with `SELECT @@event_scheduler;` If the result is `OFF` then the scheduler is not running but can be started. If the result is `DISABLED` then the scheduler can't be enabled at runtime. Only if the result is `ON` the scheduler is running. Default is `OFF`.

Comment: Thank you very much, silly mistake , yes scheduler was OFF, and i turned it on, now everything is working perfectly now.

Comment: Such things happen to everyone sooner or later, me included.

Comment: @VMai how can i debug event permonth, i have been stuck in this issue, please goes to  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400140/auto-add-field-each-user-using-event-nothing-error-and-doesnt-working) i don't know where is wrong